# How to get text from next pages using Beautifulsoup in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Im trying to get all the game outcomes for every page for a team. So far I am able to get all the opponent 1 vs opponent 2 and score outcomes. But I don't know how to get the next page to get the rest of the data. Would I find the next page and put it in a while loop ? here is the link to the team I want

http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7397-natus-vincere/matches

This is what I have so far, it gets all the team matches played and score for only the first page.

```
def all_match_outcomes():

    for match_outcomes in match_history_url():
        rest_server(True)
        page = requests.get(match_outcomes).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        team_name_element = soup.select_one('div.teamNameHolder')
        team_name = team_name_element.find('h1').text.replace('- Team Overview', '')

        for match_outcome in soup.select('table.simple.gamelist.profilelist tr'):
            opp1 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp1'}).text
            opp2 = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'opp2'}).text

            opp1_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'hscore'}).text
            opp2_score = match_outcome.find('span', {'class': 'ascore'}).text

            if match_outcome(True):  # If teams have past matches
                print(team_name, '%s %s:%s %s' % (opp1, opp1_score, opp2_score, opp2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the last page number and iterate page by page until you hit the last page.

Complete working code:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7397-natus-vincere/matches"

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # locate the last page link
    last_page_link = soup.find("span", text="Last").parent["href"]
    # extract the last page number
    last_page_number = int(re.search(r"page=(\d+)$", last_page_link).group(1))

    print("Processing page number 1")
    # TODO: extract data

    # iterate over all pages starting from page 2 (since we are already on the page 1)
    for page_number in range(2, last_page_number+1):
        print("Processing page number %d" % page_number)

        link = "http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7397-natus-vincere/matches?page=%d" % page_number
        response = session.get(link)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # TODO: extract data
```

Comment: So what happens when there are no more pages to go through does it crash?

Comment: @DJRodrigue nope, we limit it from the min to max page by the `for page_number in range(2, last_page_number+1)` loop.

Comment: it seems to be giving me and error: 
last_page_link = soup.find("span", text="Last").parent['href']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: @DJRodrigue alright, updated with a complete working code.

Comment: I think why I am getting an error is because im parsing more than just that team link and some teams don't have more than one page so there is no .parent['href']. Is that why it could be giving me an error?

Comment: @DJRodrigue ah, may be..in this case you can handle the `AttributeError` and don't initiate the loop at all since you don't have pagination there.

Comment: How would I go about doing this method if instead of a single team link I am calling a function that contains a lot of team links but not all the link match page has a next page.